# Running Javascript in Laravel 5.7 event listener

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to run a javascript library, Noty, upon user login. I've already registered the event and followed the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events). However I tried to use echo to send down the javascript, but the code isn't executing from what I can see. The workflow is that upon login in the `Home` page a noty notification will pop up saying welcome.

Here is my `EventServiceProvider`:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => ['App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserLogin']
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();


    }
}
```

`UserEventListener`:

```
class UserEventListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Login  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {

    }

    public function onUserLogin($event) {
         echo("<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    new Noty({
                    text: 'Welcome {{Auth::user()->name}}! ',
                    type:'info',
                    layout: 'centerRight',
                    timeout:2000
                })
                .on('onShow', function() {
                        var audio = new Audio('/sounds/appointed.mp3');
                        audio.play();
                    }).show();
            });
        </script>");
        echo("adad");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a very strange approach for displaying messages with Laravel.

You could simply use this line In you login controller

`return redirect('your/path')->with('success', 'your message here');`

While somewhere at your blade template perform simple check:

```
@if (\Session::has('success'))
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    new Noty({
                    text: 'Welcome {{ Auth::user()->name }}',
                    type:'info',
                    layout: 'centerRight',
                    timeout:2000
                })
                .on('onShow', function() {
                        var audio = new Audio('/sounds/appointed.mp3');
                        audio.play();
                    }).show();
            });
        </script>
@endif
```

You can put your notification code in common(for ex. layout) template so if there is a message in user's session it will fire notification anywhere

Comment: Originally I was going to figure out a way to do something similar, but with a custom variable, but found event listeners instead which kinda confused me on where to go from there. Thank you very much though!

Comment: You're welcome. Events pattern usually used to bring architecture components together so they can pass data or trigger logic of each other while they even don't know about each other. So, you were close

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do doesn't seem possible, since the listener is not going to render any HTML page (where to code would be executed) but rather it will just execute some PHP code.